# ASP .NET MVC + Angular with AOT

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, visual-studio, aot

I'm trying to run an ASP.NET MVC app using Ahead of time compilation for some Angular4 apps. I've managed to compile using the "node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json command, and obtained the ngfactory.js files. Now I'm not really sure how to configure my Visual Studio to use the AOT after adding ngfactory bootstrap in my main-aot.ts

Comment: Any solution for this?